# Corollary of Tietze extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, set-valued-analysis

The Tietze extension theorem states that a space $X$ is normal iff every continuous function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $A$ a closed subset of $X$, can be extended to a continuous function $g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tietze_Extension_Theorem). I came across the following proposition:

> A space $X$ is normal iff every lower semi-continuous multi-valued map $F: X \rightarrow 2^\mathbb{R}$ with compact and convex images admits a continuous selection.

The statement maybe requires some additional definitions:

1. A multi-valued map $F: X \rightarrow 2^Y$ is called lower semi-continuous if for every $G \subseteq Y$ open, $\left\{x \in X \mid F(x) \cap G \neq \emptyset\right\}$ is also an open set.
2. If $F: X \rightarrow 2^Y$ is a lower semi-continuous multi-valued map, we call $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous selection if $f$ is continuous and $f(x) \in F(x)$ holds for all $x \in X$.

I don't know if this is needed to prove the proposition, but I'll include it anyways; I've proved that $c(F)$, defined by $c(F)(x) = c(F(x))$ (where $c(A)$ denotes the convex hull of a set $A$), is lower semi-continuous if $F: X \rightarrow 2^Y$.

Any help with proving the blockquoted statement is appreciated, I don't really know how to get started. It does state however that the proof uses the Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: I believe this is in Dugundji's book (might be due to him as well, IIRC). But it does require some more arguments, and it's not a straightforward corollary of Tietze. I'd rather say that Tietze follows from the selection theorem.

Comment: Can we assume $F$ nonempty-valued?

Comment: @user347778 Yes.

Comment: This statement comes from a book? I know some theorems which guarantee existence of a continuous selector, but they require $X$ to be paracompact.

Comment: @user347778 The statements are not from a book, but they are inspired by Ernest Michael's article 'Continuous Selections I', published in 1956 in The Annals of Mathematics. If you take a look at the article, you'll see that Theorem 3.1. is the Tietze extension theorem and the following theorems (especially theorem 3.1') are similar. Michael states in the proof of Theorem 3.1'' $(b) \rightarrow (a)$, the if direction of my proposition stated in the question is a direct corrolary of the Tietze extension theorem. However, this is not completely clear to me. Maybe you could take a look?

Answer (score 2):

The implication from right to left isn’t too hard.

Suppose that $X$ has the continuous selection property. Let $F$ be an arbitrary closed subset of $X$ and $f:F\to\Bbb R$ a continuous function. Let $h:\Bbb R\to(0,1)$ be a homeomorphism, and let $g=h\circ f$. Define

$$G:X\to\wp(\Bbb R):x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\{g(x)\},&\text{if }x\in F\\
[0,1],&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

If $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ is open,

$$\{x\in X:G(x)\cap U\ne\varnothing\}=\begin{cases}
g^{-1}[U]\cup(X\setminus F),&\text{if }U\cap[0,1]\ne\varnothing\\
\varnothing,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

so $G$ is lower semicontinuous and takes compact, convex values. Let $\sigma:X\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous selection for $G$; then $\sigma(x)$ is a continuous extension of $g$ to all of $X$, and $h^{-1}\circ\sigma$ is a continuous extension of $f$. It now follows from the Tietze extension theorem that $X$ is normal.

I don’t immediately see how to prove the opposite implication; I’ll give it some thought after I get some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, following the same steps with the proof (b) $\to$ (a) of Theorem 3.2'' in [Continuous selections I](https://users.renyi.hu/~descript/papers/Michael_1.pdf), you can show that for every **finite** open cover of $X$ there is a partition of unity subordinated to it. The latter implies that $X$ is normal.

Otherwise, it's much easier to prove that $X$ is normal iff for every separable complete metric space $Y$ and for every compact-valued lower semicontinuous $\Phi:X\to 2^Y$ there is a compact-valued upper semicontinuous selection for $\Phi$.

If you are interested in similar characterizations of normality, you can find in ["A unified approach to continuous, measurable selections and selections for hyperspaces"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/unified-approach-to-continuous-measurable-selections-and-selections-for-hyperspaces/1AEFA4C4D5E5C9E29FD22DD95D6D46F8) (Theorem 6.5) a proof of the following result:

$X$ is normal with $dim(X)=0$ (covering dimension zero) iff for every separable complete metric space $Y$ and every compact-valued lower semicontinuous $\Phi:X\to 2^Y$ there is a single-valued continuous selection for $\Phi$.

I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This a selection theorem due to E. Michael (Theorem 3.1', [Continuous selections I](https://users.renyi.hu/~descript/papers/Michael_1.pdf)).

Comment: You are right. However, his paper does not provide a direct proof, which is what I asked for.